# how do you send a transaction to a contract in the truffle console?

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have an undefined payable function in my contract. I'm using genache all my contacts migrated and the functions work as expected nut I can't figure out how to pay this one contract from the truffle console. I have run

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:"0xB5c830d954cBf18643Df7236F0BdD6d1e48087c6", to: "0xEBBd2f9ECCf86c8E635ceDff979276fCD7EaBeA0", value: 2})
```

but I get the following error

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:96:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/wrapper.js:112:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:140:1
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:29:1)
truffle(development)> web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:"0xB5c830d954cBf18643Df7236F0BdD6d1e48087c6", to: "0xEBBd2f9ECCf86c8E635ceDff979276fCD7EaBeA0", value: 2})
```

Please help me if you can. its taken me days to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps:

https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts#making-a-transaction

1. truffle console
2. let instance = await your-contract-name.deployed()
3. instance

--> check your functions ...

Alternatively you could imo deploy to a testnet - ropsten or so.